# Click on navigation back button then navigation bar overlap same view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 3 View Controller A B and C. From B to C I can navigate portrait mode to Landscape mode. Now it is fine. When i am navigating from C to B (landscape to portrait mode) view controller. Then again now it is fine.But in C view controller i have one custom back button is there. when i click on that button it will navigate from C to B view controller. In B view controller page i am click on navigation back button it overlaps(doesn't navigate to A view controller). After two times it will be navigate to A view controller

Comment: any screenshots or code to help understanding the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your own custom view as navigation bar. check once:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

UIView *newNavBar = [[UIView alloc] init];
newNavBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:150.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

UIImageView *backgroundImgView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
backgroundImgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abc_image"];
[newNavBar addSubview:backgroundImgView];

UIButton *backBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
backBtn.frame=CGRectMake(5,15, 50, 50);//set frames according to your req
[backBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"xyz_icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(backBtnAction) //your method forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[newNavBar addSubview:backBtn];
[self.view addSubview:newNavBar];
```

This works fine for me for push/pop etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Any way i got solution for your sending code. It's indirectly helped  me  and thank you for your help